# Exception while reconnecting to a tag

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am developing an application where I want to connect a bluetooth tag with my andorid application. I am able to establish connection and do the operations. If the phone or tag goes out of bluetooth range for 20-30 seconds and come back, it will reconnect . But if I take it out of range for more than 1 min, it gives an exception

"**wrp wsock create : out of stock block**"  . What could be the reason? I am using same uudi  for connection and reconnection..I have followed bluetooth chat appliation for establishing connection..